# Can not access localhost from WebView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

In my Flutter project, there is a web view that sends a post request to a localhost server. Unfortunately, I do not have any control over the page that initiates the call to retrieve the form data being sent to my localhost, so I am unable to modify it. My only option is to change the URL. However, I am facing an issue where the localhost cannot be accessed from within the web view.

The following is a test call:

```dart
_webViewController = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            // Update loading bar.
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            print(' ${url}');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {},
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) =>
              NavigationDecision.navigate,
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5500'));
```

I tried different options like 127.0.0.1, 10.0.2.2, and my machine's IPv4 address

Comment: It is most likely a port thing.  At least in IIS, if you build an app and try to access it from the hosting machines web browser it will deny access, which I get it, its a security protection.  So you have to bind an additional port to the content and use THAT port to connect from the local/host machine to its self.

Comment: @easleyfixed I am on a Linux machine.

Comment: Yes Yes, I am just mentioning that for context of theory.  I am not sure if Linux decided to part ways with that built in security element to deny local host access for protection. or not, but my money says Linux is very secure, so likely has something like that built into it.

Comment: The fact you can't type the actual IP Address in and it allow you makes me feel like there is a port issue going on here.  You have tried using the IP address of "localhost" already I am sure?  And so once you get a non port 80 port setup for this, you would do like localhost:portnumber

Comment: As the other suggested it could be a port issue. Have you looked with something like `ss -natu` what ports are exposed?

Comment: My device just broke while trying for port 80 :) will follow up once I got it fixed